# StackOverflowException in setter with backing property

Tags: c#, asp.net, setter, stack-overflow

**UPDATE:** I have fixed the problem I was experiencing but I don't know why the bug generated the stack trace that it did.  The stack trace lead me in the completely wrong direction.  If anyone can explain what was happening here I would appreciate it (and will mark your answer as accepted).  Note that my original post has been deleted.

I had the following class.  Non-relevant parts of it have been removed:

```
class ClassName {
    private string[] _accountTypes = new string[2] {"ECOM", "MOTO"};

    private Dictionary<string, string> _settleDueDateDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
        {"0", "Process immediately."},
        {"1", "Wait 1 day"},
        {"2", "Wait 2 days"},
        {"3", "Wait 3 days"},
        {"4", "Wait 4 days"},
        {"5", "Wait 5 days"},
        {"6", "Wait 6 days"},
        {"7", "Wait 7 days"},
    };


    private string _settleDueDate;

    private string _accountTypeDescription;


    public string SettleDueDate
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
            long settleDueDate = Convert.ToInt64(_settleDueDate);
            return today.AddDays(settleDueDate).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        }
        set
        {   
            if (!_settleDueDateDictionary.ContainsKey(value)) {
                // TODO - handle
            }
            _settleDueDate = value;
        }
    }

    public string AccountTypeDescription
    {
        get {
            //return AccountTypeDescription; // This would cause infinite recursion (not referring to backing property).
            return _accountTypeDescription; // This fixed the StackOverflowException I was faxed with
        }
        set
        {
            if (!_accountTypes.Contains(value))
            {
                // TODO - handle
            }
            _accountTypeDescription = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I also had this class which took an instance of the class above and created an XML string using values from the instance:

```
class SecondClass
{
    private ClassName classnameInstance;

    public SecondClass(ClassName instance)
    {
        classnameInstance = instance;
    }

    public string PrepareRequest(XMLWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString("accounttypedescription", classnameInstance.AccountTypeDescription);
    }
}
```

Here is the client code that generated the stack trace:

```
STPPData STPP = new STPPData();

STPP.SiteReference = _secureTradingWebServicesPaymentSettings.SiteReference;
STPP.Alias = _secureTradingWebServicesPaymentSettings.Alias;

STPP.SettleDueDate = Convert.ToString(_secureTradingWebServicesPaymentSettings.SettleDueDate);
STPP.SettleStatus = _secureTradingWebServicesPaymentSettings.SettleStatus;
STPPXml STPPXml = new STPPXml(STPP);

XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Async = false;
var builder = new StringBuilder();

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder, settings))
{
    string xmlRequest = STPPXml.PrepareRequest(writer);
}
```

Finally, here is the stack trace:

```
mscorlib.dll!string.GetHashCode()
mscorlib.dll!System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer<System.__Canon>.GetHashCode(SYstem.__Canon obj)
mscorlib.dll!System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>.FindEntry(string key)
mscorlib.dll!System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.__Canon,System.__Canon>.ContainsKey(System.__Canon key)
ClassName.SettleDueDate.set(string value)
ClassName.SettleDueDate.set(string value)
ClassName.SettleDueDate.set(string value)
// Infinite recursion of this call
```

This stack trace lead me to believe that I had incorrectly implemented the getter/setter for STPP.SettleDueDate.  I checked them and the backing variable etc. was correct (the usual causes for loops in getters/setters, I understand).  Further debugging showed me that the stack trace was actually generated when this line of `PrepareRequest()` was called:

```
writer.WriteElementString("accounttypedescription", STPPData.AccountTypeDescription);
```

I discovered that I had incorrectly implemented the getter for STPPData.AccountTypeDescription because I had created a backing property that I used in the setter but I was NOT using the backing property in the getter:

```
public string AccountTypeDescription
{
    get {
        //return AccountTypeDescription; // This would cause infinite recursion.
        return _accountTypeDescription; // This fixed the StackOverflowException
    }
    // setter omitted for clarity (it is in the examples above)
}
```

My question is:

**Why did the stack trace of the StackOverflowException point me to SettleDueDate.set() when the bug was actually inside AccountTypeDescription.get()?**

Note: I'm new to C# and am coming from a LAMP background.  I have simplified the code a little but I do not think I have removed anything important.

Comment: Without knowing what `_settleDueDateDictionary` is (code) it's pretty impossible to help.

Comment: +1 for a `StackOverflowException`

Comment: @Erik Philips - Ok - I've added this into the question.

Comment: Can you create a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: You should look at the exception stack trace - it will show the method chain that results in the recursion.

Comment: @Knagis - If I didn't say, the setter of the SettleDueDate is the one that is resulting in the recursion.

Comment: why are you storing a date value as a string, instead of as a `DateTime`?

Comment: @Pete171 - that does not seem to be possible from the code that you posted - there are no recursive calls. Maybe there is some other code that you have skipped to reduce the size of it in the question?

Comment: From the stack trace it looks like there must be a `SettleDueDate = value;` somewhere in the setter (instead of `_settleDueDate = value;`), or something like that.

Comment: @Knagis - I don't know what that would be.  You have the full definition of `_settleDueDateDictionary` the `SettleDueDate` getter and setter and the private `_settleDueDate` backing variable.  The only thing I have changed is how the `anIntParameterHere` is passed to the setter.  I don't think that could be the problem?  What else could I provide?  `ClassName` otherwise just contains other getters/setters and a few other data members.

Comment: @Servy - Perhaps because I'm new to C#!  But after forming that string we need to interpolate it into XML using XMLWriter, so I think that may be OK usage?

Comment: @leppie - As above, new to C# so might be doing a few odd things... I will look at that once thi shas been resolved.

Comment: @Pete171 You should store it as a `DateTime` throughout your application and then convert it to a string just before you store it in an XML file, rather than performing operations on it throughout your application as a string.

Comment: @Knagis - I did some more debugging and found that the above code wasn't the problematic bit.  Apologies for not giving the rest of it - really didn't see how what I missed could have been the problem.

Comment: All: I have fixed the problem.  No idea why the StackOverflowException said what it did.  Problem was somewhere else.  Question rewritten to ask why this happened.

Comment: @Pete171 - Where is the code that sets `SettleDueDate`?  Is it possible you were passing the value of `AccountTypeDescription` into it and/or using that as a dictionary key?

Comment: @Bobson - Please see the third code block (my client code).  One of the lines in there (beginning `STPP.SettleDueDate = Convert.To`...) is the part that sets `SettleDueDate`.  Thanks.

Comment: @Pete171 - Ah, I missed that, thanks.  I've got nothing useful, sorry.

Comment: @Pete171 - I just had a thought.  Can you copy a small portion of your code and reproduce this?  And/or can you upload a zip of the whole directory somewhere for someone else to try and reproduce?

Answer (score 1):

Below are some simple debugging steps that should narrow down the problem

- Open up the class with SettleDueDate property
- Right click on the property name for SettleDueDate
- Click on the menu item 'Find all references'
- Every place that SettleDueDate is set ie 'SettleDueDate = "Something or other"' add a breakpoint
- Run the application and keep continuing when breakpoints are hit till one gets hit multiple times in a row
- When you found the offending point and the code is on a breakpoint instead of continuing use the Step Out command and Step over commands to trace your way back up the stack to find out where it is being assigned recursively

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've put in some breakpoints every time `SettleDueDate` is referenced but none of the breakpoints are even reached!

Answer (score 1):

This code is very fragmentary and I'm not sure I quite understand all the connections.  I'm assuming that ClassName == STPPData and SecondClass == STPPXml?  Nonetheless, I tried reproducing this bug using VS2010 and .NET 4.  I was unable to - the stack trace showed infinite recursion only within AccountTypeDescription.set().  There has to be something missing.

First of all, these lines in the stack trace are very interesting:

```
mscorlib.dll!string.GetHashCode()
mscorlib.dll!System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer<System.__Canon>.GetHashCode(SYstem.__Canon obj)
mscorlib.dll!System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>.FindEntry(string key)
mscorlib.dll!System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.__Canon,System.__Canon>.ContainsKey(System.__Canon key)
```

They appear to definitively show the innards of SettleDueDate.set(), not just infinite calls to it.  The dictionary and hash lookup are present.  You definitely have a bug *somewhere* in there.  However I have a hunch that your source code does not contain the bug.  In reference to @Bryan's answer, did you set your breakpoints *inside* the SettleDueDate setter as opposed to places in your code where *you* call it?  If you're using visual studio, you can also break on exceptions using [this feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx).

I saw that you are doing stuff with web services and that immediately makes me think of proxy classes.  They can look an awful lot like code you write, but it isn't code you write.  They can go stale.  How sure are you that this exception was thrown by code you wrote and compiled?

Secondly, web services also make me think of serialization, a process that will often call property getters and setters without your knowledge.  I've had issues in the past with WCF trying to serialize IEnumerables and failing horribly even though *my* code was just fine.

As an aside, on my system this line did not compile:

```
if (!_accountTypes.Contains(value))
```

This made me wonder if you are using Mono or a different IDE than me.  You are a LAMP guy after all =)

I know this isn't a real answer (yet), but I'm wondering what you make of this?  Any other details you can share?